# Why do format conversion libraries lack a single method to write the output to a file?

Tags: ruby, encoding, decoding, file-conversion

From my experience with Ruby, libraries that parse/convert a format (such as YAML, JSON, XML, SASS, etc.) into objects often have a single method that covers from reading the file to parsing, which is usually named like `load`, `load_file`, etc. (In addition, they usually have a method that only does parsing on a string that was read in advance, which is usually named like `decode`, `parse`. etc.)

On the other hand, when it comes to converting the objects into the target file format, such libraries rarely have a single method that covers from conversion  to writing to the destination file. Usually, they only have a single method that does only conversion, which is usually named like `encode`, `render`, etc., and the result string has to be written to the file using another method such as `File.write`.

What is the reason for this assymmetry? Why does writing to a file require an extra step?

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that it's because of error handling. Readings file can goi wrong in plenty of ways, but writing a file is even more error prone. It seems silly for a library that's main purpose is parsing to have to deal with file writing. I don't know why these libraries even include file read & parse methods.

Also, for a library to include these kinds of method is useless as soon as you need to access any of the options of the file writing and reading methods. So then the library includes an options parameter that gets passed to the file method, and now the code is just an unclear mess.

That's my 2¢.